# Laravel interaction between conrollers

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have a users controller, it controls the progress of my user through the site. It simply saves a position, as an integer (1-10) each int represents a url or position they have got to. It is a linear progression through the site.

Inside this controller I have a method that updates this integer.

```
public function updateProgress() {
  // this just increments the table by 1.
}
```

In my Pages controller I have my page redirect

```
public function nextStep(position) {
 // this just takes the updated position from the updateProgress() function and redirects to a named route based on the value
}
```

How do I get these two controllers to be able to interact.

Comment: So basically you want to call `nextStep` and make the redirect from `updateProgress`?

Comment: no next step does the redirect at the end of updateProgress  would like to just call the function nextStep(1);

Answer (score 0):

Even though it shouldn't be done, you just need to do something like below:

```
    $request = Request::create('/updateprogress', 'GET', array());
    $response = Route::dispatch($request);
    $content = $response->getContent();
    $code = $response->getStatusCode();
    $results = json_decode($content);
```

Inside array() you can define arguments if any.

You will also need to define route for this:

```
Route::get('/updateprogress', 'UserController@updateProgress'); // in routes.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should rather put the redirection logic somewhere else than your controller if you need it somewhere else. Usually controllers are only responsible for one specific route/request.

Anyways, you can just instantiate the controller and call the function:

```
public function updateProgress() {
    $position = 1; // do math here
    $pagesController = new PagesController;
    return $pagesController->nextStep($position);
}
```

If your PagesController uses dependency injection use the `app()` helper function to instantiate it through the container:

```
$pagesController = app('App\Http\Controllers\PagesController');
```